# ModSecurity problem: How to resolve that 404 error page?

Tags: 7

I have installed Drupal 7 on latest version of Nginx web server which was completed with the support of the ModSecurity module. I have activated the core OWASP rule set, but when I active ModSecurity in my virtualhost configuration file for Drupal 7, logging in, registering, or resetting passwords cause this error:

> open() "/var/www/MY_WEBSITE/node" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: IP, server: MY_SERVER, request: "POST /node?destination=node HTTP/1.1", host: "MY_WEBSITE", referrer: "http://MY_WEBSITE/"

The browser gets a 404 error page.

I found some solutions for Apache Server which modify the .htaccess file, not used from Nginx; I didn't find any solution for Nginx.

How do I solve this problem? Is there any ModSecurity rule I have to disable, or change?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You are simply stating facts, without asking any explicit question. What exactly don't you understand? What did you try to solve the issue? What solutions did you find for the Apache server?

Comment: I bet the question is something like "How to resolve that 404 error page?". If that's the case, then please ADD that to the content of your question. Also, you may want to fix multiple typos i your question (compled, acitiveted), and maybe also add some relevant hyperlinks?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Solutions for Apache server modify htaccess file and all are very old (few years ago).

Comment: Voilà, now at least we have a real question ... fingers crossed to see if it gets enough votes to have it reopened ...

Comment: @kiamlaluno I edited my post, could you reopen it please?

Comment: @kiamlaluno : good to know/see that this question got reopened. About 1 hour after the last edit by OPer, [I was the only one to vote for reopen](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/89502), while you (as a moderator) voted to leave it closed. Nothing happened with this question after that, except the previous comment that was posted by OPer (asking to reopen it). Is it really that easy to get a question on hold reopened? Ie just ask for it via a comment to do so (somewhere AFTER the reopen-review completed)? If you want, I'd be happy to move this comment to meta.drupal.SE.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens No, simply asking to re-open a question in a comment doesn't necessarily re-open the question, in the same way adding a link to a project page doesn't.